# Any way to get touch coordinates from non-UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

If I have an openGL app that has 2 threads (not created by me, these are the standard 'provided' threads).  Those being:

- GLRendering thread
- Main / UI thread

And lets say that in my rendering thread I draw a sprite like so: (The methods shown are my own methods)

```
sprite.draw(); //This will draw the sprite at it's own internal X and Y coordinates
```

Now, on the UI Thread, I capture the current finger position: (The following occurs within onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event))....

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

    sprite.setX(event.getX());
    sprite.setY(event.setY());

}
```

So, what happens is that my sprite is drawn where the finger is allowing the user to drag it around the screen.

However, clearly, the two threads aren't guaranteed to run 'alternately' like so:

> **UI Thread**: Capture finger position and set (X:10, Y:10)
>
> **Renderer Thread**: Draw at 10, 10
>
> **UI Thread**: Capture finger position and set (X:22, Y:31)
>
> **Renderer Thread** Draw at 22, 31 etc.......

The above is great, but what happens when this occurs:

> **UI Thread**: Capture finger position and set (X:10, Y:10)
>
> **Renderer Thread**: Draw at 10, 10
>
> **Renderer Thread**: Draw at 10, 10 << Draws again at the same position even though the finger has physically now moved to a different location causing an offset between object's on-screen position and the finger's physical positionon the screen
>
> **UI Thread**: Capture finger position and set (X:22, Y:31)
>
> **Renderer Thread** Draw at 22, 31 etc.......

This can seem to cause 'choppiness' in the drawing of the object.

So, what I'm asking is, is there *any* way for force the Rendering thread to somehow retrieve the *actual current physical position* of the currently-down pointer/finger before it draws it?  Or some other solution to the problem? (Put simply the problem being that the rendering thread should always have access to the current position and not the previous position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO!

The problem you are experiencing is not due to the two threads running in parallel. Instead, it is due to the fact that either

- Your frame rate is too low
- Your movement is so fast that choppiness becomes visible.

Solution to the first problem is to profile your app and reduce the lag time - try to hit the nominal frame rate of 60fps.

The solution to the second problem, however, is just a small trick. Instead of adjusting the position of the sprite to be exactly your touch points, **make it move towards the touch point**.

A crude implementation is like this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

    sprite.setNewX(event.getX());
    sprite.setNewY(event.setY());

}
```

In your Sprite Class add these:

```
private int mNewX, mNewY;

public void setNewX(int x){
   mNewX = x;
}
public void setNewY(int y){
   mNewY = y;
}
```

add these two lines to your draw method of your Sprite class:

```
public void draw(){

    this.x = this.x + (int)(0.5 * (this.newX-this.x));
    this.y = this.y + (int)(0.5 * (this.newY-this.y));
// of course, you can get rid of the "this" keywords above. I just put them there for the sake of clarity.

// drawing stuff

}
```

Comment: Hi @Kasra - Not sure I understand. I've also tried something similar to that which you suggest (getting the amount the finger has moved by & adding it to the sprite's pos).  But, when onTouch is 'skipped', this value becomes 0 and the sprite doesn't move for that tick, then on the next, it catches up and moves double.  So, with a finger moving at a constant 10 px per tick.  It would move 10, draw at +10, move 10, then (if onTouch skipped) move 0, then on the next tick move 20,  If I understand you, all you're doing is halving that amount so it wouldn't move with the finger but be slower?

Comment: Thnk of a scrollview, this is what I need.  The object 'sticks' to the finger no matter how fast or slow the finger is moving.  I need to find a way to say, 'instead of moving 0, then 20 on the next tick, just move 10 on both ticks' to keep things consistent.  Similar to Linear Interpolation I guess which I already use in my main loop (for my sprites).

Comment: So then yes - all you need to do is to implement the method I describe. I added more details to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Ah, OK, no I was reading your code in onDraw incorrectly, it's similar but not the same as that which I've tried.  Will give this a go and report back thanks @Kasra

Comment: Thanks @Kasra - got it working,  there's still a slight intermittent choppiness  so maybe there is also something else wrong.  But this does reduce the choppiness quite a bit so thanks for your help - it's much appreciated!